# Nested JSON not saving to CosmosDB using Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm having an issue where I'm using the following stack:

- .net core 6
- EF Core 6
- CosmosDB

I have the following classes.  Note that the MenuItems.Items property could be nested:

```
    public class BaseModel
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Menu : BaseModel
    {
        public string Discriminator = nameof(Menu);
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Slug { get; set; }

        public ICollection<MenuItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<MenuItem>();
    }

    // I've tried with and with the BaseModel
    public class MenuItem : BaseModel
    {
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(1000)]
        public string Url { get; set; }        

        // PAY ATTENTION TO THIS PROPERTY
        public ICollection<MenuItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<MenuItem>();
    }
```

My CosmosContext is:

```
    public class CosmosContext : DbContext
    {
        public CosmosContext(DbContextOptions<CosmosContext> options) : base(options) { }
        public virtual DbSet<Menu> Menus { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<Menu>(b =>
            {
                b.HasKey(o => o.Id);
                b.HasPartitionKey(o => o.Id);
                b.HasDiscriminator<string>(nameof(Menu.Discriminator));
            });
        }  
    }
```

And my code to save a Menu to the DB is:

```
// add a new menu with nested MenuItems
var m = new Menu()
{
    Name = "Example Menu",
    Slug = "example-menu",
    Items = new List<MenuItem>()
    {
        new MenuItem() // this one gets into the cosmosdb
        {
            Name = "Menu 1",
            Slug = "menu-1",
            Items = new List<MenuItem>()
            {
                new MenuItem() // this level doesn't exist in cosmos... Why not? :( 
                {
                    Name = "Menu 1a",
                    Slug = "menu-1a"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

context.Menus.Add(m);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

It does save and looks like this:

```
{
    "Id": "24b9e5fd-90c9-47bb-bec7-08daac957c98",
    "Discriminator": "Menu",
    "Name": "Example Menu",
    "Slug": "example-menu",
    "id": "Menu|24b9e5fd-90c9-47bb-bec7-08daac957c98",
    "Items": [
        {
            "Id": "2e8003ec-5c2e-463f-add7-08daac957ca0",
            "MenuId": "24b9e5fd-90c9-47bb-bec7-08daac957c98",
            "Name": "Menu 1",
            "Slug": "menu-1",
            "Url": null
        }
    ],
    "_rid": "uYkaAKC8Y1EBAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/uYkaAA==/colls/uYkaAKC8Y1E=/docs/uYkaAKC8Y1EBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-de7e-5a4c14e301d8\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1665608726
}
```

However, it's missing the nested *Items* property with the value of "Menu 1a".

1. I am doing something obviously incorrect?
2. Does EFCore / CosmosDB not support this?

[You can download and run the entire demo project here](https://github.com/redapollos/cosmosdb-efcore-demo)